# Routing Through URL Bar Hitting in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I copy paste a valid URL and then hit enter then useEffect on parent component in not calling. Where as If reload the page then it is calling , coding snippet is given below,

Routing path

```
<Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
```

Parent Component

```
const Search = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('abc', true);
    dispatch(getConfig(localStorage.getItem('ID')))
      .then((res) => {
        //code
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [dispatch]);
  
  return (
    <SearchResults search={search} />
  );
}
```

ChildComponent

```
const SearchResults = (search) => {
  useEffect(() => {'
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('abc'));
  }, [search]);
      
  return (
    code....
  );
}
```

How I will resolve this issue or what am I doing wrong on the above code?

Comment: It is strange, as copy-paste and hit URL also does a reload of the page. Can you share more details on it? Any test video or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly ..Interesting is this that If I hit same url 2nd Time then it is working..How do I share test video ?

Comment: Is there are any errors on the console? This problem needs debugging as the code base doesn't seem any issue, it is something else. With the given information, It is hard to tell the problem. More data is required to solve it.

Comment: No error message, I just check with console.log() ..nothing is printing.

Comment: I don't see any issue with this code *other than* the `SearchResults` component not correctly using the props object passed to it. I think we need more complete details and [mcve].

Comment: checked with props object but not work..here is my quesion how can I identify that the user clicked from url bar...

Answer (score 2):

```
// Routing path
<Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />

// Parent Component
const Search = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('abc', true);
    dispatch(getTenantConfig(localStorage.getItem('ID')))
      .then((res) => {
        // code
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <SearchResults search={search} />;
};

// Child Component
const SearchResults = ({ search }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('abc'));
  }, [search]);

  return (
    // Your code...
  );
};
```

it seems like the issue might be related to the way you're passing the search prop to the SearchResults component. You need to destructure the props correctly in the SearchResults component since you're passing it as an object. Also, ensure that you are properly rendering the SearchResults component within the Search component.

Here's how you can make sure you're passing the search prop correctly:

In the Search component, destructure the search prop when passing it to the SearchResults component:

In the SearchResults component, destructure the search prop correctly:

it's worth noting that the useEffect in the Search component is not dependent on any props or state changes ([dispatch] is an empty dependency array). If you want the useEffect in the Search component to run whenever the URL changes (and thus trigger the child component's effect), you should include the search prop in its dependency array:

If you make these changes and ensure that you're rendering the SearchResults component properly within the Search component, the useEffect in the SearchResults component should run when the URL changes, whether you navigate via a link or reload the page

Comment: Used but not worked .

Comment: The props passed to `SearchResults` have nothing at all to do with the parent component's lifecycle.